# how to create an array of fixed length strings dynamically with following constraint

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, vector

The constraint is that it should be contiguous memory. The reason is, this is being sent to another language legacy code, which expects it in that format as a 2D array.

so esentially i want to send

```
char *temp[20] = { "abc", "def"};
```

etc where `abc, def` are part of a space thats `20` byte length.
Now, i would like to dynamically create this array and add as many `20` character or less strings to it.

And then send that as an array into the different layer.
Whats the best way to do this.

Comment: why do you ask if you already gave the answer as a tag? Use std::vector...

Comment: How many character strings you want to pass ? If it's not fixed then `std::vector` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector< std::array<char, 20> >` will do the trick

`vector` allows dynamically allocating more memory for more strings, the type `std::array<char,20>` ensures that each member of the `vector` is indeed 20 characters (make sure to verify boundaries on copy etc, as with any array).

This is for newer C++ standard, IIRC, so older compilers might not support it. Use boost.array instead, then.

Comment: thanks, but what if there is no std::array support on what i am using?

Comment: @AMM: Try `<tr1/array>` and `std::tr1::array`. Unless your compiler is ancient, there's a good chance you have this.

Comment: @AMM - then you can use boost.Array, or just create a class that encapsulates a 20-chars array (which is what `std::array` does). The `T` for vector must be assignable, which `char[]` is not.

Comment: thanks, would defining my own class cause issue in terms of padding? can i use that as a contiguous location? ie...if i say struct { char[20] temp; ... define copiers and initializers } could there be padding issue or is it gauranteed to be only on 20 characters in length

Comment: @AMM - use *__atribute__ packed* (gcc) or *#pragma pack* (MSVC), or whatever else alignment control option your compiler has, if its critical. The only other way is to use plain old standard C arrays, with `malloc`s and `realloc`s.